# Code returning true but data is not in table

Tags: c#, database, ssms

I'm trying add data into a database in SSMS, According to my code, I'm getting successful insertion but in database table. I've new empty row with no data. Here is my code sample.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=OSMSSE;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout =30");
public void AddData(string word){

conn.Open();
string sql = "insert into TestBlock (Words) values(@word)"; 
SqlCommand  cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word.ToLower());
int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if ( res > 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("Inserted");
}
conn.Close();
}
```

And here is image of database table with no data.
[Database table record SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1nuW.png)

[Database table Designer SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdS3K.png)

Comment: You're creating an insert command (cmd), then executing a completely different command?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly type that here. If I do so, ofcoz it gives errors.

Comment: If you get the text "Inserted" output then you probably have a transaction going on that is being rolled back.

Comment: Does roll back still create new empty row in table ? What I'm doing wrong, can you identify mistake ?

Comment: No rollback will leave your data as though nothing happened after the transaction begins. See the comment by Soner, though - are you just looking at the wrong table?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, your table name is `TestBlock2`, not `TestBlock`. That's why you need to modify your command as;

```
string sql = "insert into TestBlock2 (Words) values(@word)";
```

Also I have a few suggestions;

1. You should not write your connection string hard-coded. You need to put it some configuration file or some settings file.
2. You probably using your `conn` as a field in your code. Instead of that, create your connection into your method.
3. You need to use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically.
4. Do *not* use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method instead (preferably [`Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_))

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question, Actually I was trying to SqlDataAdapter, So, I mistakenly type da.InsertCommand. I'm trying different approaches but still could not figure out what is the issue.

Comment: @DanishAli Updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word.ToLower());
```

This fix it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@word", (String) word.ToLower());
```

As parameters are added as Objects.

Comment: Really? I don't think that would be an issue. `ToLower` method _already_ returns `string`. Explicit casting is redundant here.